# Change the location of the ncb file in Visual C++ 2008 (9.0)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I´ve tweaked the VC++ settings so that all of my actual code will go to one place, while compiler generated binaries will go to another. This ncb file is the exception though. It is a quite large IDE generated binary file (Intellisense database). I can´t seem to be able to move it anywhere other than the solution folder. I´ve reasearched on google and found a few references saying that this is impossible. Does anyone have a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio doesn't allow you to move that file.  [This article on CodeProject](http://69.10.233.10/KB/cpp/Symbolic_Links_for_Apps.aspx) shows how one person worked around this problem, by creating a "poor man's" version of [symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link).  This involves hooking Windows' [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.  This approach seems like overkill to me; I think I would just learn to live with this limitation if possible.